# Vim: How to highlight every second line?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to set up syntax highlighting in `vim` to highlight every second row?

Comment: Do you mean visual rows, or file lines?  If the former, Vim doesn't support it. If the latter, it can probably be done, but how do you want to handle blank lines?

Comment: File lines. There are no blank lines, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I apologize, but the only way I can think of doing it is very messy. Basically you'd have to define a syntax rule for every other buffer line.

Answer (score 1):

My [DynamicSigns](https://github.com/chrisbra/DynamicSigns) plugin allows this. See the help at `:h  Signs-Alternate`

Comment: How do you install this plugin? I use pathogen, and I can't seem to get it running.

Comment: Pathogen should just work.

Comment: Alternatively, you can install the zip file from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3965

Answer (score 0):

This is very crude and messy, and I suspect there is a better way to do it, but this is what I came up with:

```
function! SynEvenLines()
    syn clear
    highlight clear EvenLines
    for l:i in range(2,line('$')+1,2)
        exe "syn match EvenLines '\\%" . l:i . "l.*'"
    endfor
    highlight EvenLines guibg=darkgrey ctermbg=grey
endfunction
```

Once you have this function sourced you can just type:

```
:call SynEvenLines()
```

If you add lines to the buffer or if you do other types of editing you will need to run the function again.

The last line of the function is where you would modify the color of your highlight.